# Cassandra LCS generation always at level 0 (performance issues?)

Tags: cassandra

We have a small set of data but very high tps for reads and writes, so we are using LeveledCompactionStrategy. When doing performance testing, we observed that the data file is always at level 0 and not moving to level 1. Am not sure if the size of the file we specified has any thing to do with it?

```
compaction={'sstable_size_in_mb': '256', 'tombstone_threshold': '0.1', 'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'} AND

xyz.json:
 "generations" : [ {
    "generation" : 0,
    "members" : [ 18627, 18628 ]
  }, {
    "generation" : 1,
    "members" : [ ]
  }, {
....
```

Questions:

1. The total size of the file may never reach 256mb in the near term, so does it mean it might cause the file will never reach level 1? Also does it cause any performance issues if its always at level 0.
2. We also noticed that similar queries are taking 4-10ms and some times taking 80-90ms. Is the compaction settings causing it?

Any help in this regard is really appreciated.

Comment: Are your writes so fast that there a pile up in L0 (meaning you are performing STC in L0 leveled compaction)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, small L0 could never reach L1. You can use STCS with min compaction threshold 2 - compacts more, but keeps 1 sstable. You can use populate IO cache on flush for that CF to keep it cached in memory after compaction.
2. If you see 80-90ms just sometimes, this could be just because of stop the world ParNew GC, which time could be similar. If you're on C* 2.0, check CF Latency metrics for percentiles.